# Запятая перед как

Tags: запятые, как

Никак не разберусь с запятой перед как в следующих предложениях, пожалуйста, подскажите.

> 1. Директор вручил Власову как руководителю оркестра благодарность от
>    отдела культуры за многолетний
>    плодотворный труд...
> 2. Человек с проблемами в физическом развитии, как гражданин, ничем не
>    отличается в праве на труд от других
>    членов общества (это предложение, мне
>    кажется, построено неправильно.
> 3. Как диетолог, полностью одобряю программу "Покупай нижегородское".

Я расставила запятые так, как думаю. Вы согласны со мной?
В первом предложении запятые не ставила.
А второе предложение, может быть, переделать так:

> Человек с проблемами в физическом
> развитии, как гражданин, имеет право
> на труд, как и другие члены общества.

Надеюсь на вашу подсказку.

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

> Директор вручил Власову как руководителю оркестра благодарность от
> отдела культуры за многолетний
> плодотворный труд...

Я бы сделал так:
*Директор вручил руководителю оркестра Власову благодарность от отдела культуры за его многолетний плодотворный труд...*

Или так:
*Директор вручил Власову благодарность от отдела культуры за многолетний плодотворный труд его на посту руководителя оркестра…*

> Человек с проблемами в физическом развитии, как гражданин, имеет право
> на труд, как и другие члены общества.

Я бы убрал "как гражданин". А "право на труд" заменил бы словами из Конституции (в Конституции РФ такого понятия, как "право на труд", нет):

*Человек с проблемами в физическом развитии имеет такое же право свободно распоряжаться своими способностями к труду, выбирать род деятельности и профессию, как и любой другой член общества.*

> Как диетолог, полностью одобряю программу "Покупай нижегородское".

По-моему, нормально.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответы.

Answer (score 1):

В первом предложении запятая не нужна, союз как имеет значение "в качестве''. Во втором предложении  (хотя оно построено некорректно) запятая нужна. Союз как имеет значение причинности. Т.к. он (человек) является гражданином... В третьем предложении запятая также нужна. Оборот с союзом "КАК" имеет значение причинности. Будучи диетологом...